# Rxjava - How to check if Maybe/Observable is empty properly?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I am accessing database using Maybe and my goal is to call the network if Maybe will complete indicating that there is no data in database (I am using room). I have following functions:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Item>> getResults() {
    return getResultsFromDatabase().toObservable().switchIfEmpty(getResultsFromNetwork());
}

@Override
public Observable<List<Item>> getResultsFromNetwork() {
    System.out.println("getting results from network");
    return api.getData().doOnNext(new Consumer<List<Item>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<Item> items) throws Exception {
            itemDao.insert(items);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Maybe<List<Item>> getResultsFromDatabase() {
    System.out.println("getting coins from database");
    return itemDao.getAllItems();
}
```

However, the switchIfEmpty works a little unexpectedly, as it is always called, even though there are objects in database.

```
return getResultsFromDatabase().toObservable().switchIfEmpty(getResultsFromNetwork());
```

1. Is it possible to transform Maybe into Observable using only toObservable()?
2. Is there another way to check if Maybe will be empty and then act upon it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Single` instead of `Maybe`. Because when there are no rows in db, `Maybe` will be completed directly without calling error. But `Single` will result in `onError` with `EmptyResultSetException` when there are no rows. We can then use Rx's power to return the data from network call. Here's how:

First change your `itemDao.getAllItems()` to return `Single<List<Item>>`.
Then change `getResultsFromDatabase()` to return `Single` as well like:

```
@Override
public Single<List<Item>> getResultsFromDatabase() {
    System.out.println("getting coins from database");
    return itemDao.getAllItems();
}
```

Now you need to use `onErrorResumeNext` in order to return the data from network call, so change the `getResults()` to:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Item>> getResults () {
            return getResultsFromDatabase()
                    .toObservable()
                    .onErrorResumeNext(new ObservableSource<List<Item>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void subscribe(io.reactivex.Observer<? super List<Item>> observer) {
                            getResultsFromNetwork();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Why can't **Maybe** return `onComplete()` when there are no rows?

Comment: Maybe returns onCompleted() when there are no rows. But it doesn't return error in such case so I suggested to use Single and then return the data from network in that error.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the reason why `getResultsFromNetwork` is called that you are passing its return value to switchIfEmpty, rather than its reference?

I would change it to e.g.

```
getResultsFromDatabase().toObservable().switchIfEmpty(Maybe.Callable(this::getResultsFromNetwork))
```

and see if it helps